# Granting Login Access via Licence Management App by Users

Tags: managed-package, isv, partner, lma

We are an ISV partner and our customers use our package 24/5 on for a mission critical purpose. We are using LMA to support them using "Grant Login Access" feature. The problem we are dealing with is that if a non-admin user grants us access, we will not have the full access we may need to resolve the issue. Since the solution is mission critical we may not have the time to wait for an admin to grant us their login access. As an example, think of a representative in a night desk while the admin is not at work.

One option would be to have our own user for these cases but I'm looking for a better solution. How do other partners deal with this problem?

Comment: I'll typically have a direct user login to each subscriber org as well. It will have the highest access profile that the subscriber is comfortable granting. I can then grant myself login access to get to the managed package logging.
It's not ideal, but I'm not aware of a better alternative.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Interestingly enough, this was the solution we came up with but I was hoping I can find a better solution...

Comment: Another reason why having a direct user with higher perms is useful. Accessing the debug log. Often the user your debugging won't have perms sufficient to capture the debug logs. So you need to create the TraceFlag from the elevated ISV login then Login As the target user to cause the debug log to be captured.